# When is Normalized LMS better than LMS?

Tags: adaptive-filters, lms

I see mention that normalized LMS "usually converges faster than LMS", in Diniz "Adaptive Filtering" p.152, can this be made more precise? IE, for which signal distributions does it hold?

I'm in particular interested in overparameterized regime where misadjustment is zero for LMS and NLMS.

---

[image]